# count number of rows in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some questions in my database. I display only one question per page with a "NEXT" button. When the user clicks on next button I display the next question from the database randomly.

So the problem is when user reached has the last question I want to change the "NEXT" button name to "FINISH".

please help me how to do this..

```
this is my count query:
$nRows = $dbh->query('select count(*) from questions')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $nRows;
```

This is my next button in my application.

```
<button  id='Next'  class="next-button" name="submit_<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $key ?>" onclick="change_next(this.value)">Next</button>
```

this is my java script code to display one question per page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         function change_next(value) 
    {
    if(value == 0) 
    {
         var next = value;
         next++;

        $('#question_'+value).removeClass('active').addClass('hidden');
        $('#question_'+next).removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
    } 
    else 
    {
        var next = value;
        next++;

        $('#question_'+value).removeClass('active').addClass('hidden');
        $('#question_'+next).removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to chagne the value of the button

```
    var count = 0;
    function change_next() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          if (count == 5) {
             //document.getElementById("Next").value="FINISH";  <--sorry this is if you are using <input type="button" not button =/
             document.getElementById("Next").innerHTML="FINISH";
          }
          count++;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "Load_Question.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: how can we do the same thing in ajax

Comment: When you do your call 'change_next' - Add the above code in to the ajax calls return, this will change the buttons name

Comment: So now when you click on "Next" button, you load a question randomly with PHP, but you want to do it without loading your page by loading questions with Ajax that's right ?

Comment: Have you got a set number of questions?

Comment: @nenroz no nennroz..i already display questions with out refresh the page..my problem is when i reached the last question i would like to change the  button name to Finish. automatically..

Comment: @krisph no krisph can you please tell me how can we do that

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
function showNextQuestion() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      count+=1;
      if(count>=3) {
         document.getElementById("Next").innerHTML="Finish";
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "QuestionLoader", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button  id='Next'  class="next-button" name="submit_<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $key ?>" onclick="change_next()">Next</button>

function change_next()
{
    document.getElementById("Next").value="FINISH"; 
}
```